# How to understand perfect syntax for creating Pandas Dataframe from different objects like dictionaries and sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to learn Pandas Dataframe from different objects like lists , ndarrays , dictionaries , sets etc.. I understand that the syntax for creating a dataframe as given in the official website is as follows

```
DataFrame([data, index, columns, dtype, copy])
```

But why is it that the square brackets(as displayed in the syntax) not needed in every scenarios . I am not able to understand when and where to use the square brackets .The code I have tried is as given below

Code 1

```
my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'}
print(pd.DataFrame([my_set]))
```

Code1 want me to provide 'my_set' within square brackets without which it will generate an error

Code 2

```
my_dict = {'T':(2,3),'z':(5,6)}
print(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))
```

why is the syntax not followed in the code2. Why is square bracket not needed in code2

Code 1

```
my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'}
print(pd.DataFrame([my_set]))
```

Code 2

```
my_dict = {'T':(2,3),'z':(5,6)}
print(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various parts to this qn so answering one by one.

1. Here is the DataFrame constructor copied from the documentation and there is not square bracket.

   class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
2. The square bracket denotes list so if you are using a Python list to construct a DataFrame, you would us the square bracket.

   pd.DataFrame(['T','a','g','s','l'])
3. If your data type is set and not a list, you can convert the set to list and use it to construct the dataframe.

   my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'}
   pd.DataFrame(my_set)

You get

```
    0
0   a
1   s
2   T
3   l
4   g
```

4. If you pass the set in a list, you are creating a 2-D structure,

   my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'}
   pd.DataFrame([my_set])

   ```
       0   1   2   3   4
   0   a   s   T   l   g
   ```
5. Similarly you can create a dataframe from dictionary, no need to square brackets

   my_dict = {'T':(2,3),'z':(5,6)}
   pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

   ```
       T   z
   0   2   5
   1   3   6
   ```

Comment: Hi Vaishali ,Thanks for the reply . I have a few concerns here . 

1) I referred to the below link for the syntax
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html

Why is it different from the one u provided
2) When i tried to run the code
my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'} 
print(pd.DataFrame(my_set))

I got an error saying  "DataFrame constructor not properly called!" Does that mean that we cannot create a dataframe directly from a set

Comment: The constructor lists the parameters in the Class DataFrame. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py). [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) is the code for pandas DataFrame. For your second qn, I am quite surprised about the error because the code worked for me. Can you check the code again please.

Comment: my_set = {'T','a','g','s','l'} 
print(pd.DataFrame(my_set))

i run the above code and it gives me the error message. So I assume that we cannot convert a set to a dataframe . It must be enclosed in square brackets .So we are actually converting set to a list 

print(pd.DataFrame([my_set]))
the above code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Without the brackets, both code 1 (the set) and code 2 (the dict) work for me. In Python, the brackets are the syntax for denoting a list. So `[my_set]` would mean a list containing a single element which is a set.

The brackets you saw here

```
DataFrame([data, index, columns, dtype, copy])
```

I believe are meant to denote optional parameters rather than a list. You could create an data frame without passing any arguments e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame()`, so it is indeed likely the case that it just means optional parameters. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for more information and examples on creating data frames.

Comment: Hi Mark ,thanks for the reply . I used the syntax from the below link

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html

Why is it different from the one you have provided ?

Comment: I think the page you're on is just a listing of all the related functions for `DataFrame`. I don't know why the writers of the documents chose to have such a discrepancy when describing signatures. Again, keep in mind that the actual way the `DataFrame` class is created is the same, they just chose to explain it a little differently.

Comment: Thanks Mark.

print(pd.DataFrame([my_set])) .This code works just fine .

print(pd.DataFrame(my_set)) . Without square brackets this code generates an error message "DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Does that mean that we cannot convert a set to a dataframe .But if the set is converted to a list , then we can.

Comment: Both Vaishali and I confirmed that using a set works for us without putting it in a list. You can also see [here](https://repl.it/repls/FlippantJauntyKilobyte) that it works without errors. You may be using an older version of Pandas? Furthermore, I explained in my answer that `[my_set]` does not convert the set to a list but rather puts the set _in_ a list. A conversion would instead be done like so: `list(my_set)`.